# Apache Redirect: to prepend 'www' and Clean URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, rewrite

I am administrating an Apache/2.2.15 webserver with several virtual hosts.
For one of these hosts I want to always prepend a missing `www.`. Besides that, I want to add several short-cut URLs.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /short /some-long-URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301]
```

With these rules, accessing an URL of the form `http://my-domain.org/some-URL` is rewritten and redirected to `http://www.my-domain.org/some-URL`, which is exactly what I want.
However, when accessing `http://my-domain.org/short`, I get redirected to `http://www.my-domain.org/`. It seems like the Redirect rule for `/short` is never being applied... But accessing `http://www.my-domain.org/short` is correctly being redirected to `http://www.my-domain.org/some-long-URL`.

I hope someone knows a solution and can explain to me, what I am doing wrong.

Regards,
Immanuel

PS: I would also appreciate it if the solution would also work with RewriteRule with PassThrough instead of a redirect :)

Comment: `With these rules, accessing an URL of the form` - The description you give for what's happening doesn't match the rules in the question (you can counter/disprove this comment by adding the output of `curl -I http://my-domain.org/some-URL` etc. to the question). If you want things to work with PassThrough - start by not redirecting  /short to /long, and use a rewrite rule for it _with passthrough_ =).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Rewrite changing domain

A drop in rewrite rule to [rewrite example.com → www.example.com](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/2.11.0/dist/.htaccess#L407-L414) is:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

As mentioned by BillThor, `http` can be replaced with `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` to be scheme independent.

### What's wrong with the rules in the question?

> I hope someone knows a solution and can explain to me, what I am doing wrong.

This rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R=301]
```

Has no capture group, hence $1 is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I would define the virtual host to have the desired domain as its server name.

```
# Virtual host definition with desire canonical name
ServerName      www.example.com
ServerAlias     example.com
Use CanonicalName on
```

You could use a passthrough rule to avoid the redirect.  This is invisible to the client (browser).  There are multiple ways to redirect the request.  I've shown two.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Handle rewrite without redirect (passthrough) 
RewriteRule /short /some-long-URL [PT]

# Or use a redirect (scheme and server not required as of 2.2.6)
Redirect /short http://%{SERVER_NAME}/some-long-URL

# Or use rewrite and redirect  
Rewrite ^/short some-long-URL [R]
```

If you use canonical names, you can just redirect non-matching hosts.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^%{SERVER_NAME}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I generally use hostnames instead of using %{SERVER_NAME}.  If you use the same configuration for both HTTP and HTTPS, you may want to use %{REQUEST_SCHEME} instead of `http` in the URLs